# Parsley: Creating an ObjectDefinitionBuilder from an ObjectDefinition

Tags: apache-flex, parsley

I'm working on a framework extension for Parsley, and need to effectively clone an `ObjectDefinition` during initialziation of the context, and mutate some of it's properties.

As `ObjectDefinition`'s are inherently immutable, I'm finding I have to jump through hoops to create a new builder that safely ensures the properties of the existing `ObjectDefinition` have been copied across.

Is there a way to safely create a new `ObjectDefinitionBuilder` from an existing `ObjectDefinition`?

If not, what other alternatives exist for creating an `ObjectDefinition` clone?

Comment: Can you post what you're actually trying to do with the extension?  You might not be going about it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a more elegant solution, but I ended up doing this long-hand.

In my specific case, I want to change the class of the registered object, but keep the other properties.  Here's the approach I ended up using:

```
private function cloneDefinition(objectDefinition:ObjectDefinition,replacementClass:Class):ObjectDefinition
{
        switch (true)
        {
            case objectDefinition is DefaultSingletonObjectDefinition:
                return new DefaultSingletonObjectDefinition(ClassInfo.forClass(replacementClass),objectDefinition.id,objectDefinition.registry);
            case objectDefinition is DefaultDynamicObjectDefinition:
                return new DefaultDynamicObjectDefinition(ClassInfo.forClass(replacementClass),objectDefinition.id,objectDefinition.registry);
        }
        throw new Error("Support for cloning object definitions of type " + getQualifiedClassName(objectDefinition) + " not yet supported");
}
```